# Determine if this language is context-free

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

Let
$$L_1=\{W_1@W_2 \mid \exists k \text{ such that } |W_1|>|W_2|\ge k, W_1[k]=W_2[k],\Sigma =\{0,1\}\}$$
where $k$ is an arbitrary number and $W_i[k]$ means the $k$-th character in $W_i$.
So this is the language and I want to know if it is context-free or not.
I've tried to write a grammar for this language, based on another one that I've written:
$$L_2=\{W_1@W_2 \mid \exists k \text{ such that } |W_1|,|W_2|\ge k,W_1[k]=W_2[k],\Sigma =\{0,1\}\}$$
And the grammar is: (The $S$ is the starting variable)
$S\to A1X \mid B0X$
$X\to LX \mid L$
$L\to 0 \mid 1$
$A\to LAL\mid 1X@$
$B\to LBL \mid 0X@$
But every grammar I wrote had some flaws. If you want I can write my latest grammar and its flaw.
Sorry for my bad English, I'm not native :)
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What is $k$ in your context? Is it arbitrary chosen at the start? What does $W_1[k] = W_2[k]$ mean? That the first $k$ elements are the same?

Comment: @LegNaiB good points, I'll add them now, I forgot, Thanks!

Comment: I still have a problem with the parameter $k$. Does that mean that all characters $i=1,...,k$ have to be equal or just the single character at point $k$. But where is the $k$ implemented in the grammar for $L_2$? Because of the unknown parameter $k$ I honestly think that both grammars are not context-free. Maybe the Pumping Lemma can help to show that.

Comment: @LegNaiB I know that it's a little confusing, but it was an example in our theory of languages and machines class. The strings that the second grammar is producing have this property: For a specific $k$, $W_1[k]$ is equal to $W_2[k]$. Or you can say it in another way: There is at least one $k$ so that $W_1[k]$ is equal to $W_2[k]$. Maybe the second language is not a context-free language, but I think with the Pumping Lemma you can only say that a language is not regular. Again, sorry about my poor English :)

Comment: Your english is not poor, I'm not a native speaker as well :) It is a fundamental difference if there is some $k$ s.t. these two characters are equal or if you have the $k$ predefined. I edited your question so that it is more clear where the $k$ is coming from (did I edit it correctly?) There exist a version of the Pumping Lemma for context-free grammars as well. I will have a look at the language later today

Comment: @LegNaiB Yeah, I didn't notice that different point of view. Thank you for your edit, and as far as I know, it's correct. thank you for your time :)

Comment: @III_phr There is a [pumping lemma for context-free languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages), too.

Comment: @frabala ah I didn't know that, thank you :)